# Full gradient descent in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement full gradient descent in keras. This means that for each epoch I am training on the entire dataset. This is why the batch size is defined to be the length size of the training set.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD,Adam
from keras import regularizers
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline  
import random
from numpy.random import seed
import random

def xrange(start_point,end_point,N,base):
    temp = np.logspace(0.1, 1, N,base=base,endpoint=False)
    temp=temp-temp.min()
    temp=(0.0+temp)/(0.0+temp.max()) #this is between 0 and 1
    return (end_point-start_point)*temp +start_point #this is the range

def train_model(x_train,y_train,x_test):
    #seed(1)
    model=Sequential()
    num_units=100
    act='relu'
    model.add(Dense(num_units,input_shape=(1,),activation=act)) 
    model.add(Dense(num_units,activation=act))
    model.add(Dense(num_units,activation=act))
    model.add(Dense(num_units,activation=act))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='tanh')) #output layer 1 unit ; activation='tanh'
    model.compile(Adam(),'mean_squared_error',metrics=['mse'])
    history=model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=len(x_train),epochs=500,verbose=0,validation_split = 0.2 ) #train on the noise (not moshe)
    fit=model.predict(x_test)
    loss = history.history['loss']
    val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
    return fit

N = 1024
start_point=-5.25
end_point=5.25
base=500# the base of the log of the trainning
train_step=0.0007
x_test=np.arange(start_point,end_point,train_step+0.05)

x_train=xrange(start_point,end_point,N,base)
#random.shuffle(x_train)

function_y=np.sin(3*x_train)/2
noise=np.random.uniform(-0.2,0.2,len(function_y))
y_train=function_y+noise
fit=train_model(x_train,y_train,x_test)

plt.scatter(x_train,y_train, facecolors='none', edgecolors='g') #plt.plot(x_value,sample,'bo')
plt.scatter(x_test, fit, facecolors='none', edgecolors='b') #plt.plot(x_value,sample,'bo')
```

[image]

However when I uncomment the #random.shuffle(x_train) - in order to shuffle the trainning.
 [image: plot]:

I don't understand why I get different plots (the green circles are the trainning and the blue are the are what the modern learned). as in both cases the batch is of ALL the dataset. So the shuffle shouldn't change anything.
Thank you .

Ariel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens for two reasons:

- First, when the data is not shuffled, the train/validation split is inappropriate.
- Second, *full* gradient descent performs a single update per epoch, so more training epochs *might* be required to converge.

---

### Why doesn't your model match the wave?

From [model.fit](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit):

> - **validation_split**: Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the training data
>     to be used as validation data. The model will set apart this fraction
>     of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate the loss
>     and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch. *The
>     validation data is selected from the last samples in the x and y data
>     provided, before shuffling*.

Which means that your validation set consists of the last 20% training samples. Because you are using a log scale for your independent variable (`x_train`), it turns out that your train/validation split is:

```py
split_point = int(0.2*N)
x_val = x_train[-split_point:]
y_val = y_train[-split_point:]
x_train_ = x_train[:-split_point]
y_train_ = y_train[:-split_point]
plt.scatter(x_train_, y_train_, c='g')
plt.scatter(x_val, y_val, c='r')
plt.show()
```

[image: Train - validation split]

In the previous plot, training and validation data are represented by green and red points, respectively. Note that your training dataset is *not* representative of the whole population.

---

### Why does it still not match the training dataset?

In addition to an inappropriate train/test split, *full* gradient descent *might* require more training epochs to converge (the gradients are less noisy, but it only performs a single gradient update per epoch). If, instead, you train your model for ~1500 epochs (or use mini-batch gradient descent with a batch size of, say, 32), you end up getting:

[image: Result]

Comment: does "adam" use mini-batch by default if I use `.fit` without any extra specifications? I though min-batch was specifically for things like GD/SGD, not Adam.

Comment: @VISQL the optimization algorithm is independent of the batch size (which defaults to 32 in [fit](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)). Setting `batch_size=1` yields SGD, whereas `batch_size=nb_total_samples` corresponds to full gradient descent. You can perform mini-batch gradient descent by setting a value in between (that's the most typical choice).